# MouseLeave event not firing for anchor and other inline elements

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a link to a codepen and the problem is best observed in Chrome:

https://codepen.io/pkroupoderov/pen/jdRowv

The mouseLeave event does not fire sometimes when a user quickly moves the mouse over multiple images, meaning that some images will still have the grayscale filter applied. How to fix that? If I use a div instead of an anchor element it works totally fine. Should I slightly change the markup or apply certain styles to the anchor element?

I'm trying to create an overlay effect on an image when a user hovers over one just like on Instagram. I will add the content to the overlay later I just need to solve that mouseLeave event issue. CSS pseudo styles is not going to work since the overlay needs to have content in it.

```
const imageUrls = [
  'https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7909/33089338628_052e9e2149_z.jpg',
  'https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7894/46240285474_81642cbd37_z.jpg',
  'https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7840/32023738937_17d3cec52f_z.jpg',
  'https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7815/33089272548_fbd18ac39f_z.jpg',
  'https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4840/40000181463_6eab94e877_z.jpg',
  'https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7906/46912640552_4a7c36da63_z.jpg',
  'https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4897/46912634852_93440c416a_z.jpg',
  'https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4832/46964511231_6da8ef5ed0_z.jpg'
]

class Image extends React.Component {
  state = {hovering: false} 

  handleHover = () => {
    this.setState({hovering: true})
  }
  handleLeave = () => {
    this.setState({hovering: false})
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.hovering) {
      return (
        <div onMouseOver={this.handleHover}>
          <img src={this.props.url} alt='' />
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      return ( // works fine when using <div> tag instead of <a> or <span>
        <a href="#" style={{display: 'block'}} onMouseLeave={this.handleLeave}>
          <img style={{filter: 'opacity(20%)'}} src={this.props.url} alt='' />
        </a>  
      )
    }
  }
}

const Images = () => {
  return (
    <div className="gallery">  
      {imageUrls.map((image, i) => {
        return <Image key={i} url={image} />
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Images />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your mouse is leaving the component before it is able to rerender the new element to the page.  I would suggest not conditionally rendering different elements into the component, and just use conditions to render styles differently inside your a tag.

My solution would be to change the render function in your Image component to something like this

```
render() {
  return ( // works fine when using <div> tag instead of <a> or <span>
    <a href="#" style={{display: 'block'}} onMouseLeave={this.handleLeave} onMouseOver={this.handleHover}>
      <img style={{filter: this.state.hovering ? 'opacity(20%)' : 'none'}} src={this.props.url} alt='' />
    </a>  
  )
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GzaGgq

Comment: Awesome, it works like a charm. I was able to achieve my end goal by using this concept.